# How does "-dc" work in "cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc "01"?

Tags: command-line, tr

So far I know,
the `/dev/urandom` file is one of the special files, it's purpose is to generate random characters.
When I execute `cat /dev/urandom` a stream of strange characters, some even Chinese ideograms are displayed continuously.
However, if I pipe this stream of strange characters into `tr` with the option `-dc` it makes a random stream of 0 and 1 or whatever characters are put into quotation marks in `tr -dc "setofcharacters"`.

I tried to read the manual for tr, but under `-d` and `-c` I get explanations that I do not understand or could make sense of, like

> ```
>    -c, -C, --complement
>           use the complement of SET1
>
>    -d, --delete
>           delete characters in SET1, do not translate
> ```

could someone please be so kind and deliver a step by step explanation of the logic behind `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc "01"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the biggest problem is to understand what “complement” means in the description of the `-c` option. It refers to complement as in set theory, read about it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)):

> In set theory, a complement of a set A refers to things not in (that
>   is, things outside of) A.

Complement of set `01` means all characters except 0 and 1. Thus, the `-d` option will remove all characters that are neither 0 nor 1.

Answer (score 3):

-d means delete all caracters in SET1 and -c means use the "complement" of SET1. Combined, it means: delete all caracters that are not in SET1

Your are getting a list of characters, including 0's and 1's, and the tr -dc "01" is deleting all characters that are not in the list "01", displaying only 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 1):

The complement option simply gives you the inverse set of the set you provide. So if you give it 01, its going to affect everything that is not a 0 or a 1 ASCII character. And the delete option will delete the selected set.  So you are simply deleting everything on input that is not a 0 or 1 ASCII character.

Please understand though that these are only ASCII characters from the output of /dev/urandom, they are not the actual binary values representing the output of all the characters in /dev/urandom.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [tr manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html) carefully, you can explain the command easily.

The general form:

```
tr [option]... set1 [set2]
```

With your command:

```
tr -dc "01"
```

`set1` contains `0` and `1`. With `-c` option, `tr` will replace `set1` with its complement, which mean all characters except `0` and `1`.

So, the command can be interpreted as *Delete all characters except zero and one*.